# Eclipse doesn't see CLASSPATH

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I have some JAR files on my `CLASSPATH` environment variable. When I open `cmd` and enter `echo %CLASSPATH%`, the paths to those JARs are part of the output. When I try to compile and run a java class through `cmd` that imports classes from these JARs, it works, and I don't have to add the JARs with `-cp`.

But when I try to import these classes in Eclipse, it doesn't work. The import cannot be resolved. I have to add them to the build path.

This means that when I get a new version of a library, I have to add it to the build path, and remove the old version, for each project that uses the library. I also have to recompile the projects that I have runnable JARs of, because each uses its own separate copy of the library (which, by the way, just seems wasteful and unnecessary). If it worked as I intended, I'd only have to change the version number in `CLASSPATH`.

Is it possible to make it work like I intended? Or is there a better way to handle JARs and JAR updates?

Comment: That's what dependency managers like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) are for.

Comment: @DimaLih Do Eclipse users make that joke in IntelliJ questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [User Library](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm?cp=1_4_2_0_1_1) in the preferences and refer to that in your projects' **Java Build Path**s, changing the JAR files it contains as needed. For updating your runnable jars automatically, that might well be better suited to a system such as Ant or Maven. As for having redundant copies in your Runnable JARs, that's just part of what makes them "runnable."